# IOS - IAP - user management

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, user-management

Im trying to integrate IAP - In-App purchases to one of my course purchasing app.

So after going through apple docs and concept of using apple id for payment to be associated with my app user account.

So i want to understand, can we restrict application user account associated with apple id(receipt) for payments to be allowed to user. Because my app contains subscription type products, which cannot be allowed to re-purchase with another user account if user login in same iphone.

how does the other education apps are managing access to courses to specific user accounts?

Comment: You can't get the actual Apple ID. You need to track the receipt. Assuming you are using auto renewing subscriptions then what you would typically do is track the purchase receipt on your server if user "A" purchases a subscription (using AppleID 1) you record that on your server. If user "B" subsequently restores/purchases the same subscription using Apple ID 1 (which will show up with the same original transaction id in the receipt) then you can deny the activation for user B or remove access from user "A" and assign it to user "B".

Comment: If you are using non auto renewing subscriptions then the second purchase will be charged and you simply associate the subscription with user B. User A continues using their original subscription.

Comment: @Paulw11 In case of auto renew subscription , if user "B"  restores/purchases, i dont want to allow user to make payment request (that will show apple alert that you have already subscribed), before that i need to verify receipt belongs to user "A", and want to deny it. is that possible? Is there any unique info in receipt which i can rely on, to associate with user "A"?

Comment: You can check the current receipt against your server but refreshing the receipt may prompt the user for their Apple ID password, which may be confusing for the user. You can use the original transaction is from the receipt.

Comment: @Paulw11 your suggestion for using original transaction id for subscription purchase will work fine, But how to check for non-renewing subscription type in the same above scenario?

Comment: For non renewing subscriptions you are 100% responsible for tracking expiration. It isn't possible for the user to restore their purchase. Once a non renewing subscription is linked to an account in your backend there is no way the user can link it to different account.